# ExtJS 4 cell "renderer" problem

Tags: extjs, datagrid, cell

After reading [this article](http://www.sencha.com/learn/grid-faq/), I've managed to change rendering.

I'm calling an internal function:

```
renderer: this.onRenderCell
```

And this function is like this:

```
onRenderCell: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex,
  colIndex, store, view) {
  metaData.css = 'ini-cell-pas-traduit';
  return '&laquo;'+value+'&raquo;';
}
```

If you read carefully I return `'&laquo;'+value+'&raquo;';` so for **each** value it is transformed to: '**«value»**'; . This is a proof that on every single line, it works perfectly. So should it be for the css. But the css is applied one time out of two!! This drives me nuts.

Here's what it gives (latest Firefox, same with latest Chrome):

[image: ExtJS cell css problem]

Any idea where I should take a look?

Here's a big sample of my source code:

```
Ext.define('Lang.grid.Panel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.langgrid',

    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',
        'Ext.form.field.Text',
        'Ext.toolbar.TextItem'
    ],

    initComponent: function(){

        this.editing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing');

        Ext.apply(this, {
            iconCls: 'icon-grid',
            plugins: [this.editing],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    iconCls: 'icon-add',
                    text: 'Add',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onAddClick
                }, {
                    iconCls: 'icon-delete',
                    text: 'Delete',
                    disabled: true,
                    itemId: 'delete',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onDeleteClick
                }]
            }],
            columns: [{
                text: 'label',
                flex:2,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'label'
            },{
              header: 'fr',
              flex: 3,
              sortable: true,
              dataIndex: 'fr',
              renderer: this.onRenderCell,
              field: {
                type: 'textfield'
              }
            },{
              header: 'es',
              flex: 3,
              sortable: true,
              dataIndex: 'es',
              renderer: this.onRenderCell,
              field: {
                type: 'textfield'
              }
            },{
              header: 'us',
              flex: 3,
              sortable: true,
              dataIndex: 'us',
              renderer: this.onRenderCell,
              field: {
                type: 'textfield'
              }
            }
            ]
        });
        this.callParent();
        this.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', this.onSelectChange, this);
    },

    (...)
    (snip useless code)
    (...)

    onRenderCell: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex,
      colIndex, store, view) {
      metaData.css = 'ini-cell-pas-traduit';
      return '<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">&laquo;'+
        value+'&raquo;</span>';
    }
});
```

Comment: by one time out of two you mean like a row is rendered and one is not ?

Comment: Can you post more source code

Comment: Hope my editing may help you... to help me =) Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the metadata.css (ini-cell-pas-traduit) do this for `background-color`

```
background-color : red !important //or whichever color you've specified.
```

**EDIT :**
This is happening because the grid is configured with `stripeRows : true`. I dunno if this is done by default or you did it in the config but forgot to mention it here. When you use `stripeRows` it sets a `background-color` which can be overriden using the `!important` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem came from the fact that I had: `background-color:rgb(255,155,155);` without the `!important` keyword.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got an answer, and a good one here (the Sencha forum is almost useless nowadays...)

Answer (score 2):

Varun Achar is right about using !important, but since you are using Ext JS 4 you should also change

> metaData.css = 'ini-cell-pas-traduit';

to

> metaData.tdCls = 'ini-cell-pas-traduit';

The 'css' and 'attr' members of metaData have now been replaced with tdCls and tdAttr and the old ones will only work in Ext JS 4 if you also install the Ext 3 compatibility layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint, I put "up" so your answer stays close to the one I checked as valid. Thanks again.