# How to write the Xpath for the Dynamically generated ID by Extjs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extjs4

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApDuc.jpg)Iam finding difficulty in getting the Xpath for Dynamically generated ID by Extjs.My application is using ExtJs rich UI.
Could you any one help me out'
This div is inside a table

Sample Html[Sample HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as6vM.jpg)

In this id ext-genXXXX changes in every refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add custom css class to the control element, e.g. see this: [In ExtJS, how to add a custom CSS class to data grid rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637770/in-extjs-how-to-add-a-custom-css-class-to-data-grid-rows), and then use By.cssSelector instead of By.id?